# crossdomain.xml on WCF Service hosted by Windows Service

Tags: wcf, service

I am trying to make my Windows Service, which hosts a WCF service cross-domain compatible.
After hours and hours of searching I was told that I needed to create another service which will load the crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml files so that the Windows hosted WCF service can be run on any domain.

This is my main service :

```
Namespace UmbrellaMobileService


<RunInstaller(True)> _
Public Class ProjectInstaller
    Inherits Installer
    Private process As ServiceProcessInstaller
    Private service As ServiceInstaller
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.Container

    Public Sub New()
        process = New ServiceProcessInstaller()
        process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem
        service = New ServiceInstaller()
        service.ServiceName = "UmbrellaMobileService"
        service.DisplayName = "Umbrella Mobile Service"
        service.Description = "Handels Umbrella Mobile Requests."
        Installers.Add(process)
        Installers.Add(service)
    End Sub
End Class

<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)> _
Public Class UmbrellaMobileService
    Inherits ServiceBase
    Public serviceHost As ServiceHost = Nothing
    Public CrossDomainServiceHost As ServiceHost = Nothing

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        ServiceBase.Run(New UmbrellaMobileService())
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        ServiceName = "UmbrellaMobileService"
    End Sub

    'Start the Windows service.
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args As String())
        If serviceHost IsNot Nothing Then
            serviceHost.Close()
        End If
        serviceHost = New WebServiceHost(GetType(UmbrellaService), New Uri("http://localhost/UmbrellaMobileService"))
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IUmbrellaMobileService), New WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost/UmbrellaMobileService")
        CrossDomainServiceHost = New ServiceHost(GetType(CrossDomainService))

        Else
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Umbrella Mobile Service", objIniFile.ErrorMessage, EventLogEntryType.Error)
            serviceHost.Close()
            CrossDomainServiceHost.Close()
        End If

        serviceHost.Open()
        CrossDomainServiceHost.Open()
    End Sub

    ' Stop the Windows service.
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnStop()
        If serviceHost IsNot Nothing Then
            serviceHost.Close()
            CrossDomainServiceHost.Close()
            serviceHost = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(Requirementsmode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)> _
Public Class UmbrellaService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    Implements IUmbrellaMobileService

    Function GetCustomers() As Stream Implements IUmbrellaMobileService.GetCustomers
    'Function Logic
    End Function


End Class
```

End Namespace

This is my Implementation of my main service:

```
Namespace UmbrellaMobileService
<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface IUmbrellaMobileService


    <OperationContract()> _
       <WebInvoke(Method:="GET", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
    Function GetCustomers() As Stream


End Interface
```

End Namespace

This is the 'Cross Domain Service' I was advised to add:

```
Namespace UmbrellaMobileService
Public Class CrossDomainService
    Implements ICrossDomainService
    Public Function ProvidePolicyFile() As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message Implements ICrossDomainService.ProvidePolicyFile
        Dim filestream As FileStream = File.Open("ClientAccessPolicy.xml", FileMode.Open)
        ' Either specify ClientAccessPolicy.xml file path properly
        ' or put that in \Bin folder of the console application
        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(filestream)
        Dim result As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, "", reader)
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

End Namespace

And here is its Implementation :

```
Namespace UmbrellaMobileService
<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface ICrossDomainService
    <OperationContract(), WebGet(UriTemplate:="ClientAccessPolicy.xml")> _
    Function ProvidePolicyFile() As Message
End Interface
```

End Namespace

My config file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="CrossDomainServiceBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="UmbrellaMobileService.UmbrellaMobileService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="UmbrellaMobileService.IUmbrellaMobileService">
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/UmbrellaMobileService"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
            <service name="UmbrellaMobileService.CrossDomainService">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="UmbrellaMobileService.ICrossDomainService" behaviorConfiguration="CrossDomainServiceBehavior"/>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/></system.web></configuration>
```

Now, I get this error when I attempt to run this service:

*Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Service has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. 
This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, 
or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.*

I have searched and searched and still do not know what to do, can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Is there anyone that can help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here is how I fixed it.
First, create a new service class that will serve up the clientaccesspolicy.xml when a client requests it:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class CrossDomainPolicyService
{
    private Stream StringToStream(string result)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/xml";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
    }

    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/clientaccesspolicy.xml")]
    public Stream GetClientAccessPolicy()
    {
        string result = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <access-policy>
        <cross-domain-access>
         <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers=""*"">
            <domain uri=""*""/>
        </allow-from>
        <grant-to>
            <resource path=""/"" include-subpaths=""true""/>
        </grant-to>
        </policy>
        </cross-domain-access>
        </access-policy>";

        return StringToStream(result);
    }
}
```

Next, modify your app.config file to expose the new service:

```
      <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="policyBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="MyNamespace.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespace.IMyService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9876/MyService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="MyNamespace.CrossDomainPolicyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespace.CrossDomainPolicyService" behaviorConfiguration="policyBehavior">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <!-- Root Domain where the other service is hosted -->
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9876/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

... and that should do it!